# Storage engine MEMORY is disabled with digitalocean managed database

Tags: mysql, digitalocean

I have this error:

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"error_code":-1,"sql":"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_exrecipient_dc8f2500b15714f5703ad66bc5a8bb37` (contact_id int primary key) ENGINE=MEMORY COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci","debug_info":"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_exrecipient_dc8f2500b15714f5703ad66bc5a8bb37` (contact_id int primary key) ENGINE=MEMORY COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci [nativecode=3161 ** Storage engine MEMORY is disabled (Table creation is disallowed).]","entity":"Mailing","action":"create","is_error":1,"error_message":"DB Error: unknown error","debug_information":"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_exrecipient_dc8f2500b15714f5703ad66bc5a8bb37` (contact_id int primary key) ENGINE=MEMORY COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"}

on a civicrm installation which uses a managed database at DigitalOcean.

This happens when adding a new group as recipient of a mailing. Instead of showing the recipients' count, civicrm shows an "estimating" locked message.

I'm pretty sure this is not a problem with civicrm, but with the managed database. Sorry to ask this here, but I'm stuck. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

SOLUTION: Demerit's answer helped me to work around the problem, but the solution came from setting internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine to MEMORY with [DigitalOcean API](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/databases_patch_config). You need to wait some time for the new setting to have effect.

UPDATE: DigitalOcean disabled the ability to set internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine by setting disabled_storage_engines to "ARCHIVE,BLACKHOLE,CSV,MEMORY,MRG_MYISAM,MyISAM", so the workaround has become the solution :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would edit CRM/Utils/SQL/TempTable.php and change the 3 places where it says `MEMORY` to `InnoDB` instead so it always uses InnoDB.

I would also then enable the scheduled job [Clean-up Temporary Data and Files](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_cleanup) just to make sure those tables get cleaned up.

Comment: But then I would have to do that change every time I upgrade civicrm, wouldn't I?

Also, wouldn't it be much easier to change `const MEMORY = 'ENGINE=MEMORY';` of line 67 to `const MEMORY = 'ENGINE=InnoDB';` ??

Comment: Confirmed that this fixed the problem, but I don't like to change the source code...

Many thanks, anyway!

Comment: It might not be too hard to make that more configurable with a setting. Are you up for [making a PR](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/#open-a-pull-request)?

Comment: Sure. I'm working on it: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4782

Comment: Done: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28191